# What directories to backup on ESXi apart from the VMs?

Tags: backup, vmware-esxi

I know how to backup the VMs in the datastore, but what about the ESXi config?

In case of a disaster recovery (like fire and such) which directories should I backup off-site to be able to restore an ESXi configuration?

I know about these:

```
/bootbank
/altbootbank
```

Are there others?

**Edit:**

Note I'd like to move Microsoft Windows out of the equation (especially since VMware is doing the same with the vSphere Client, i.e. [not being able to do certain operations on ESXi 5.5 with it any more](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2342634)).

My aim was to do it *from* a *nix machine (ESXi is very limited in what it can do, and I'd like to keep it that way, i.e. not install many things on it to keep it as stable as possible).

Comment: How are you performing a backup of the ESXi system? What method are you using?

Comment: Preferably `rsync` or `ssh` based as I'm from the *nix background.

Comment: [First result from Google "backup esxi configuration"](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2042141)

Comment: @MikeNaylor that's the thing: I did search before asking and the first usable link that Google showed me for that was this one, requiring Windows: http://professionalvmware.com/2010/05/how-to-backup-esxi-configuration-the-missing-piece/

Comment: The problem is the PowerCLI functionality [isn't supported in linux](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp#com.vmware.powercli.ug.doc/GUID-D2B5587D-F135-4C0B-9805-45EEF4044FCA.html).  Backing up the configurations and restoring them is best done as recommended using the PowerCLI.  The other option is a direct shell connection as mentioned in the KB.

Comment: @MikeNaylor it seems CLI is supported on *nix. Will try that when back home later this week.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that it supported Redhat at the bottom of the link.

Comment: @MikeNaylor no problem. If you got a penny for each of the things I didn't see (:

Comment: especially after reading a bunch of tech papers.... been researching other stuff lately and it all bleeds together after a while... :-p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look at purpose-built VMware backup tools. You will be *very* disappointed if you treat an ESXi host like a Linux/Unix server.

Use the [VMware backup commands](https://serverfault.com/a/550282/13325) from a separate station, and you'll be left with a nice configuration tarball. I would find another approach for the actual VM backups.

Edit: Host-based example

```
vim-cmd hostsvc/firmware/sync_config
vim-cmd hostsvc/firmware/backup_config
```

This stores the config in `/scratch/downloads`:

```
# vim-cmd hostsvc/firmware/backup_config
Bundle can be downloaded at : http://ip.of.esxi.host/downloads/52fd67ba-2fdf-9876-6651-46c3da638f1a/configBundle-centaur.ewwhite.net.tgz
```

Also see: http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2013/02/how-to-backup-restore-free-esxi-host.html

Comment: I'll edit my question, as I'd like to move Microsoft Windows out of the equation (especially since VMware is doing the same with the vSphere Client, i.e. not being able to do certain operations on ESXi 5.5 with it any more). But if that's the best way to go...

Comment: Oh, you can use the CLI to do the same thing. Windows is not required.

Comment: Thanks. Please add a reference like that to your answer and I'll +1 and accept it. Something like https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_VMWare_vCLI