# ESXi 5 Hypervisor fatal boot error

Tags: vmware-esxi, boot, usb-flash-drive, buffer

For over 2 years now I've been running ESXi 5 just fine from a pen drive. I recently had to move the server to a new location and started seeing an issue.

Once the system starts to boot, I get:

'Error Loading /s.v00

Fatal error: 6 (Buffer too small)'

I'm not quite sure what could be happening. Nothing has changed. The only thing that was different is that the system was off and unplugged for 2 days.

In my google searches a few other started to see this issue after a power failure. The rig is connected to a UPS and I made sure to cleanly shutdown all guests and then the host itself.

What can I do here?

Answer (score 1):

USB drives can fail. This is caused by either a corrupted file or bad media and can occur at random.

My general advice is to only boot ESXi from USB or SDHC card if you have SAN/NAS-based storage for your guests and are operating in a cluster. Otherwise, this can happen and cause unnecessary and frustrating downtime.

Please see: [What happens when the USB key or SD card I've installed VMware ESXi on fails?](https://serverfault.com/questions/549253/what-happens-when-the-usb-key-or-sd-card-ive-installed-vmware-esxi-on-fails)

Also, [this may be repairable](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/VMWare/A_13595-HOW-TO-Fix-the-Error-loading-s-v00-Fatal-error-33-Inconsistent-data-in-the-VMware-vSphere-Hypervisor.html), but *likely* isn't worth the effort. You may just have to reinstall ESXi onto known-good media and reimport your disk-based datastores and virtual machines.