# ESXi host loses connectivity to embedded USB storage

Tags: vmware-esxi, usb, embedded

Referencing ewwhite's SF question/answer here: [What happens when the USB key or SD card I've installed VMware ESXi on fails?](https://serverfault.com/questions/549253/what-happens-when-the-usb-key-or-sd-card-ive-installed-vmware-esxi-on-fails)

I have a real simple question.  We deal with this constantly and a reboot of the host has always caused the host to boot fine and connect again to the embedded USB drive again.

SO my question is:  Is there any way to possibly reconnect to the embedded USB storage WITHOUT a reboot of the host to remove this error assuming the USB stick is still fine?  I've tried a rescan of the HBAs/storage, and a reset of the hardware sensors, but no go.  VMWare support said "you'll have to reboot" but I'm wanting a second opinion just to make sure.

Comment: Can you provide details on the hardware involved?

Comment: @ewwhite - It varies, but so far they are all Cisco UCS C240 or B series blades with the Cisco provided USB thumb drive installed.  Or did you need other specifics?  Also, if it matters it's all been on 5.1 hosts.  I haven't seen the same issue yet on 5.5 hosts, but I also haven't found definitive proof from Cisco that an update fixes this issue.

Comment: Are your UCS blades actually using thumb drives or SD cards (FlexFlash) presenting themselves as USB drives?  If the latter, you should have an option in the IMC to reset the controller without a reboot.

Comment: For virtual environnement I always suggest a USB to RJ45 box. That way your VM can be on any host, and still see the USB, as the VM connect via the network stack to the USB. Work for dongle, hdd, etc..

Comment: @BrandonXavier - I'll look but I'm pretty certain this one in particular is just a thumb drive.  I'll check the IMC anyway.