# What is the use case of a SD slot on motherboard?

Tags: hardware, storage, hp-proliant

My HP Proliant ML110 G7 has a full-size SD slot on the motherboard. What is its use case?

The [PDF manual](http://content.etilize.com/User-Manual/1023140008.pdf) mentions it on `page 10: item 17` just to show its placement, but nothing more. In a later revision (Gen 9), it is said the slot is not hot-pluggable.

[image: HP Proliant ML110 G7-motherboard]

The motherboard also has a USB slot (item 11).

Comment: Some system even offer  adual sdcard slot to make a mirror of them for your system

Comment: I have several dell R610 servers that have 1 Gbyte of flash on the mainboard, and no hard drives/no backplane.  Had they been built with a SD slot I could have upgraded the card and continued using them, instead of parking them in the spare parts store.

Comment: But you *can* use them: boot off from USB/PXE, mount a NFS/iSCSI share and you are done...

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It's for booting a hypervisor or lightweight operating system like VMware ESXi.

See: [What happens when the USB key or SD card I've installed VMware ESXi on fails?](https://serverfault.com/questions/549253/what-happens-when-the-usb-key-or-sd-card-ive-installed-vmware-esxi-on-fails)

Comment: That explains the "not hot-swappable" warnings on HP Gen8 spec sheets!

Answer (score 21):

By installing an embedded hypervisor/OS on the SD card, you leave all the front-bay disks available for data storage. This is an useful logical and practical separation.

Some servers have two RAID1-ed SD slots: if a single SD fails, the system continue to run from the mirror, leaving you the time to replace the failed SD.

The most widely installed embedded hypervisor probably is ESXi, with a footprint less than 2 GB.

Comment: My motherboard has also a USB slot. I doubt they can be raid-ed though.

Comment: The USB port is mainly intended to put in a USB stick if you need to transfer some extra data (like drivers) to the server while you are installing it.

Comment: @Tonny I think the OP is talking about an **internal** USB slot, which is used exactly as the SD one: to install an embedded OS/hypervisor without touching the data disks.

Comment: For a while, the internal USB port was sometimes intended to run a tape drive.

Comment: My Supermicro X-10 series motherboard has a USB B connector mounted on the board. I use it to hold the OS, a dedicated NAS appliance.  @Criggie it's odd that your internal tape drive did not have a jumper-header connector instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SD card for example to outsource the /boot partition. e.g HP ProlianG8 G8 can not boot from HDD when the RAID controller is configured to HBA but you can still boot from the SD-Card.

Also you may by able (not tested) to outsource EFI fat partiotion to the SD-Card to by able to create a software RAID and load kernel / init from there.

FYI: Unfortunately the internal SD Card slot on Supermicro motherboards cannot be used for OS / boot partition and according to Supermicro is reserved for internal debugging use only

https://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=29646

Answer (score 1):

Some years ago, the embedded PC motherboard used in a product had a CF card slot on the motherboard.  The SD is probably a modern update to that.

For a device that will run embedded firmware, not a desktop or conventional server (e.g. a specialized medical imaging printer) this is a specific feature desired of the board.

As I recall, it was running Embedded XP, an older MS product for that purpose.