# VMware ESXi boots to black screen with only one text line: "usb"

Tags: vmware-esxi, boot, usb, hypervisor

After rebooting my server (Lenovo System X), my ESXi instance starts to boot and then hangs up after the Yellow/Grey screen. I have a black screen, with a white "usb" on top.

I found similar issue with "[scrath](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2047642-vmware-esxi-6-0-boots-to-black-screen)" or "[ssh](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/552809-esxi-booting-to-a-black-screen-with-ssh-at-top)" text, but not "usb". 
I tried to reboot several times, with the same result.

I can't find any documentation about this behavior.

Note: my ESXi is installed on the hypervisor USB flash drive.

Comment: Does it boot off a 'fresh' new USB drive?

Comment: Is all of the hardware on the VMware HCL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did your USB drive fail?

Because, if so... the system probably won't boot.
(this is a good reason NOT to use USB boot for standalone hosts)

See: [What happens when the USB key or SD card I've installed VMware ESXi on fails?](https://serverfault.com/q/549253/13325)

Comment: I installed a fresh ESXi on a new USB, and restored the VM from the datastore.